# How to calculate the expected value for each value in random values

Tags: probability, expectation

I am applying the following equation in my PhD project to calculate the correlation between different random values (i.e., we call these values as fitness values):

[image]

Let's assume we have the following values: 5.8 - 15.8 - 10.9 - 62.12 - 79.2 - 49.6

t in the equation means the position of the value, for example, when the value of t=1 is 5.8

s is the number of steps which means that when t=1 and s=1 then we are pointing to the value that is one step away from 5.8 which is 15.8

My question is that how to calculate the expected value of ft and the expected value of ft+s? I couldn't understand how to get the expected values of these two values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that depending on $s$ you would have a different coefficient of correlation. I'm not sure for your example, but I met this when computing the empirical autocorrelation function for time series:

\begin{equation}
r_h = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t = h+1}^T(\frac{y_{t-h} - \bar{y}}{s_y})\times(\frac{y_{t} - \bar{y}}{s_y})
\end{equation}

for your case i.e. if $h = 1$

```
r <- c(5.8, 15.8, 10.9, 62.12, 79.2, 49.6)
sum(((r[-6] - mean(r)) / sd(r))*((r[-1] - mean(r))/sd(r)))/6 = 0.38
```

Or you can use ACF function in R.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I still don't understand how to calculate the expected value in the equation I showed. I am trying to compare my equation to the one you showed to understand the expected value `E`

Comment: @Nasser, 1)$\mathbb{E}(x) = \int x f(x)dx = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ you have equality since you have descrete distribution. So it explains why I can use sum. (also in this case $f(x) = 1$, since the density is uniform).

2) $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}(XY) - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}(X))(Y - \mathbb{E}(Y))].$ It explains how I move from your formula to mine.

Comment: @Nasser, (I add a little bit more explanation) 1)$\mathbb{E}(x) = \int x f(x)dx = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ you have equality since you have descrete distribution. So it explains why I can use sum. (also in this case $f(x) = 1$, since the density is uniform).

2) $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) = \mathbb{E}(XY) - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}[(X - \mathbb{E}(X))(Y - \mathbb{E}(Y))].$ It explains how I move from your formula to mine.

So in your case, you basically have two RVs. $X = f_t$ and $Y = f_{t+s}$. And depending on $s$ you calculate different $R(t,s)$.

Comment: Thanks Koval. I am a bit confused about the first part, the equation $$ \mathop{\mathbb{E}}(x)=\int xf(x)dx $$ is related to continuous random variables and then you showed the equality of $$ \frac{1}{T}\sum_{i=1}^{N}X_{i} $$ which is related to the discrete distribution. How is that done? Forgive me for my misunderstanding.

Comment: @Nasser, no problem. Yes, you are right integral for continuous and sum for the discrete distribution. I just mixed the notation, what is not a good idea.
For your case you have $\mathbb{E}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^T x_i f(x_i) = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{i=1}^T x_i$ , since $f(x) = \frac{1}{T}$ - uniform. 

Sorry for misleading, I just get used to the integral notation so much.